# UITapGestureRecognizer - Detecting if there's a sprite at tap location (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, tap

I'm making an iOS game and need to know how to get the location of tap for uitapgesturerecognizer. I do **NOT** want to use touchesBegan, touchesEnded, etc. I also need to know how to check if a user double tapped the sprite node. I already have set up uitapgesturerecognizer's all I need to know is how to find the location of touch and see if it is the same location as a sprite node.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: let target = gesture.view!, let translation = gesture.translation(in: self.view). Now just fetch the translation.x and translation.y to get position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your sprite is of a class that inherits from UIView (and I think they generally are) the handler function for the gesture recognizer should look like this.

```
func handleDoubleTap(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let tapLocation = gestureRecognizer.location(in: gestureRecognizer.view)
    if mySprite.frame.contains(tapLocation){
        print("tapped")
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem dude :)